# create jdbc connection and retrieve the first values of the first 4 columns

Tags: java, jdbc

I need your help in creating a java bean to retrieve the first 4 columns in a table called "m_connection". I want to retrieve the first 4 columns and store them in variables. 
They are all string.

Comment: It is also recommended that you provide some code samples or more details as to the work that you tried to demonstrate that some work was attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code sample may help you:

```
    String sql="select one,two,three,four from table where id=1";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("");//get connection here
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    String[] result = new String[4];
    while(rs.next()){
        result[0] = rs.getString(1);
        result[1] = rs.getString(2);
        result[2] = rs.getString(3);
        result[3] = rs.getString(4);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all you need to establish jdbc connection then think for the data retrival**

for jdbc connection you need to follow

1. Load the JDBC driver.
2. Define the connection URL.
3. Establish the connection.
4. Create a statement object.
5. Execute a query or update.
6. Process the results.
7. Close the connection.

refer [details](http://www.javacamp.org/moreclasses/jdbc/jdbc.html)